# disabled javascript popup in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have ng-click button when I click on it, I run an ajax call like the following:

```
 function Click(data){

            var  obj = {'data':data};
            return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url:("x.php"),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: $.param({data:obj}),
            })
                .then(complete)
                .catch(function(message) {
                    throw new Error("XHR Failed ",message);
                });

            function complete(data, status, headers, config) {

            }

        }
```

then I am trying to navigate to another route while the ajax call is still running and I get a message: 
Do you want to leave the site?

I don't want pop up like that at all.

I tried to put window.onbeforeunload = null;  in each page but it is not working

How can I disable it?

Also, sometime I get a refresh popup.

My routing:

```
    // Optimize load start with remove binding information inside the DOM element
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
    // Set default state
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
              url: "/",
              templateUrl: "x.php",
              controller: 'xController',
              controllerAs: 'vm',
              resolve: {
                   fun: function(x) {
                     return x.get();
                   }

              }
            });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('saHttpActivityInterceptor');
```

Comment: what do you use for navigation? $state.go or $location ?

Comment: @Danish updated the question $state

Comment: so $state.go("pathName") works well, you must be using some kind of confirm on exit code for this behavior?

Comment: @Danish I want to disable at all, don't want any popup

Comment: Please check if you are using "confirm" in the related files?

Comment: @Danish thanks, can you give me an example how to do that and where ?